# Sci fi novel where the hero has a knife sheath in his arm

Tags: story-identification, novel

Read some time in the early 2000s as a teen, so details may be a little hazy.

Points I'm more confident about:

- Sci-fi novel following a male lead
- Starts with lead living daily life in a slum on some kind of mining planet, focus around manual labour for those in the slums, with heavy guard presence
- Male lead receives an exosuit, either taken from a guard or as part of mining duty, either the forearm of the suit has a recess for a knife, or the lead has a recess in his arm he can hide one in.

Hazy / Questionable things I can remember:

- Explosion in the slums leads to an uprising amongst the miners, lead either joins up with a resistance, or escapes the planet
- Later in the book he's part of a military / resistance unit, fighting in urban environments along with a female sniper
- I think there was a section on their training and how they came to form a unit, possible virtual reality training involvement
- A few sexual encounters throughout the book, can't remember who / which points of it.

I think maybe 150-300 pages total, not sure if a standalone or part of a series.

Comment: I suppose it's not a duplicate because one is about a particular book, the other about the whole series, so I'll just say: highly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205505/28516

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like [*Sten*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2557) by Chris Bunch and Allan Cole; it's the first book of an 8-book series called [*The Sten Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sten_Chronicles).

Sten is a young man on the factory world of Vulcan.  After his parents (migrant workers doing manual labour and living in substandard slum-like housing) are killed by the Baron Thoresen, he ends up as an outlaw (a "Delinq").

He has a knife sheath built into his forearm, and stores a knife there.

He is recruited to the Emperor's special forces (the scene where he has to fly a helicopter without even knowing what one is was humorous) and sent with his team on a mission to overthrow the Baron.

[image: Cover of Sten]

I don't recall his love interest, but the rebellion his team starts on Vulcan matches the fighting in urban environments you remember.

Comment: In the last couple of volumes of the series, Sten's latest girlfriend was named Cind. She was, in fact, an expert sniper. At the end of the series, it looked like the two of them were going to stay together indefinitely, although I don't recall anyone saying, in so many words, "Let's get married now!"

Comment: It is indeed! I just looked at alternate covers and instantly recognised the 2000 release of the first book. Thanks guys!

Comment: I knew what it was as soon as I read the title.  Knife sheath in arm gave it away.  Good set of books, I have the whole set in paperback.

Comment: @Lorendiac - Bet was his girlfriend in the beginning. They reunite when Sten returns to Vulcan.